# Meeting rooms in exchange

Tags: exchange-2010

Is it possible to add resources to a meeting when you are not the organiser?

for example, I get calendar requests from vendors to come visit, I would like to book a room for this meeting but outlook doesn't appear to allow me to add a resource to that meeting as an attendee.

instead, I end up creating a duplicate meeting but with only myself and the meeting room.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an exchange box in front of me, so I cant say for sure...  There should be a permission/setting in the exchange admin tools that allows a group of users to control a resource if they arent an admin.